# How to build a libcurl x64 static lib whose release is 1.1.1

Tags: c++, libcurl

As we known, the builder process have changed after 1.1.0.
Currently, we just run nmake after perl Configure VC-WIN64A. However, a dll is just built out.
How can i build a static lib, instead of a dll.

Thanks

Comment: Can you pass --disable-shared to configure?

Comment: After adding --disable-shared , my command is "perl Configure VC-WIN64A --disable-shared", it still don't take any effect. The dll is built, instead of static lib.